# Can i use solrj (version - 6.6.3 ) client library against solr server with lower version(5.xx or 4.xx)?

Tags: java, apache, solr, solrj

I am currently using following solr dependency in my java project:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And my solr server version is 4.xx , do i need to upgrade my solr server version or it is backward compatible?

Answer (score 1):

There's a major change in how the state for the collections are stored - in earlier Solr versions the cloud state for each collection was stored in one single file on the root in Zookeeper, but this changed later to instead keep the state for each collection in its own state file.

The more recent version of SolrJ probably expects to have per collection state instead of the global state, so if you're using the cloud mode, you should use the same version of SolrJ as you use for Solr.

For using the standard http interface for single cores, there shouldn't be much difference (I don't think the javabin format has changed for example), except for features that are only supported on newer versions of Solr than 4.

But the main question then is; if you're actually managing your dependencies properly with Maven; why not use the SolrJ library that is actually designed for your Solr version, instead of risking any possible incompatibilities in weird edge cases? I'd go with the same version of SolrJ as the version you're using for Solr.